# Hyperledger fabric: error validating DeltaSet while creating channel

Tags: hyperledger

I need to create 3 channels under 3 orgs.

channelAll : Org1,Org2

channelOrg1 : Org1

channelOrg2 : Org2

However, I have successfully created the first and second channel but for the 3rd, the error happens as below.

> Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update:
>   error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Application
>   not satisfied: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies,
>   required 1 remaining
>   root@871fcf2002f9:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer#

Do you have any ideas to resolve? here's configtx.yaml.

Profiles:

```
TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
        Capabilities:
            <<: *OrdererCapabilities
    Consortiums:
        LCFNConsortium:
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
pfAllChannel:
    Consortium: LCFNConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org2
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
pfOrg1Channel:
    Consortium: LCFNConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
pfOrg2Channel:
    Consortium: LCFNConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org2
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that orderer is not getting signature of desired organization MSP. You can verify it in orderer logs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the MSPs that you export as env `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID` before signing your envelope are correct. If your MSP is `org1.example.comMSP` then `Org1.example.comMSP` won't work.